# CSRF token is available only after successful CRX login, which is causing my login POST request to fail

Tags: aem

We are upgrading from CQ 5.6 to 6.1, Our login POST AJAX request is failing due to invalid CSRF token. On Debugging we noticed that /libs/granite/csrf/token.json is returning a valid token only after successful CRX login otherwise it is returning an null value. So at the time of login, CSRF-Token is undefined and it is causing login post request to fail. Is there anyway to exempt the login post request alone from CSRF filter? or how can we fix this

Answer (score 0):

The "j_validate" field was missing in our login form, once we added it, it resolved the issue.
input type="hidden" id="j_validate" name="j_validate" value="true".

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/secure_sites.html